# How to sort strings in React JS

Tags: reactjs

I have a table from Ant Design where i want to sort a column. This column is `name`.

```js
const data = [
  {
    key: "1",
    name: "John Brown",
    age: 32,
    address: "New York No. 1 Lake Park"
  },
  {
    key: "2",
    name: "Carl Green",
    age: 42,
    address: "London No. 1 Lake Park"
  },
  {
    key: "3",
    name: "Joe Black",
    age: 32,
    address: "Sidney No. 1 Lake Park"
  },
  {
    key: "4",
    name: "Jim Red",
    age: 32,
    address: "London No. 2 Lake Park"
  }
];

class App extends React.Component {
  state = {
    filteredInfo: null,
    sortedInfo: null
  };

  handleChange = (pagination, filters, sorter) => {
    console.log("Various parameters", pagination, filters, sorter);
    this.setState({
      filteredInfo: filters,
      sortedInfo: sorter
    });
  };

  clearFilters = () => {
    this.setState({ filteredInfo: null });
  };

  clearAll = () => {
    this.setState({
      filteredInfo: null,
      sortedInfo: null
    });
  };

  setAgeSort = () => {
    this.setState({
      sortedInfo: {
        order: "descend",
        columnKey: "age"
      }
    });
  };

  render() {
    let { sortedInfo } = this.state;
    sortedInfo = sortedInfo || {};
    const columns = [
      {
        title: "Name",
        dataIndex: "name",
        key: "name",
        sorter: (a, b) => a.name.length - b.name.length,
        sortOrder: sortedInfo.columnKey === "name" && sortedInfo.order,
        ellipsis: true
      },
      {
        title: "Age",
        dataIndex: "age",
        key: "age",
        sorter: (a, b) => a.age - b.age,
        sortOrder: sortedInfo.columnKey === "age" && sortedInfo.order,
        ellipsis: true
      },
      {
        title: "Address",
        dataIndex: "address",
        key: "address",

        sorter: (a, b) => a.address.length - b.address.length,
        sortOrder: sortedInfo.columnKey === "address" && sortedInfo.order,
        ellipsis: true
      }
    ];
    return (
      <>
        <Table
          columns={columns}
          dataSource={data}
          onChange={this.handleChange}
        />
      </>
    );
  }
}
```

Now, when i sort in ascending order the data does not order in the right way. Why? And how to solve?
demo: https://codesandbox.io/s/reset-filters-and-sorters-antd494-forked-m3ljo?file=/index.js:143-2169

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your sort compare function is comparing the length of `name` which will sort the array by the length of the name.

Change your `sorter` for `name` to below.

```js
sorter: (a, b) => {
  if(a.name < b.name) { return -1; }
  if(a.name > b.name) { return 1; }
  return 0;
},
```

You also need to change `sorter` for address.

```js
sorter: (a, b) => {
  if(a.address < b.address) { return -1; }
  if(a.address > b.address) { return 1; }
  return 0;
},
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this sorter function for name:

```
sorter: (a, b) => a.name.toUpperCase().localeCompare(b.name.toUpperCase())
```

Answer (score 0):

I've Tried this code on your snippet and it is working good -

```js
import React from "react";
import ReactDOM from "react-dom";
import "antd/dist/antd.css";
import "./index.css";
import { Table } from "antd";

const data = [
  {
    key: "1",
    name: "John Brown",
    age: 32,
    address: "New York No. 1 Lake Park"
  },
  {
    key: "2",
    name: "Carl Green",
    age: 42,
    address: "London No. 1 Lake Park"
  },
  {
    key: "3",
    name: "Joe Black",
    age: 32,
    address: "Sidney No. 1 Lake Park"
  },
  {
    key: "4",
    name: "Jim Red",
    age: 32,
    address: "London No. 2 Lake Park"
  }
];

class App extends React.Component {
  state = {
    filteredInfo: null,
    sortedInfo: null
  };

  handleChange = (pagination, filters, sorter) => {
    console.log("Various parameters", pagination, filters, sorter);
    this.setState({
      filteredInfo: filters,
      sortedInfo: sorter
    });
  };

  clearFilters = () => {
    this.setState({ filteredInfo: null });
  };

  clearAll = () => {
    this.setState({
      filteredInfo: null,
      sortedInfo: null
    });
  };

  setAgeSort = () => {
    this.setState({
      sortedInfo: {
        order: "descend",
        columnKey: "age"
      }
    });
  };

  render() {
    let { sortedInfo } = this.state;
    sortedInfo = sortedInfo || {};
    const columns = [
      {
        title: "Name",
        dataIndex: "name",
        key: "name",
        sorter: (a,b) => (a.name > b.name) ? 1 : ((b.name > a.name) ? -1 : 0),
        sortOrder: sortedInfo.columnKey === "name" && sortedInfo.order,
        ellipsis: true
      },
      {
        title: "Age",
        dataIndex: "age",
        key: "age",
        sorter: (a, b) => a.age - b.age,
        sortOrder: sortedInfo.columnKey === "age" && sortedInfo.order,
        ellipsis: true
      },
      {
        title: "Address",
        dataIndex: "address",
        key: "address",
        sorter: (a,b) => (a.address > b.address) ? 1 : ((b.address > a.address) ? -1 : 0),
        sortOrder: sortedInfo.columnKey === "address" && sortedInfo.order,
        ellipsis: true
      }
    ];
    return (
      <>
        <Table
          columns={columns}
          dataSource={data}
          onChange={this.handleChange}
        />
      </>
    );
  }
}

ReactDOM.render(<App />, document.getElementById("container"));
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.6.3/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.6.3/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
```